# How to determine multiple checkboxes states

Tags: c#

```
 UCmultiple uc = new UCmultiple(); //here UCmultiple is User Control  it contains checkbox
 string strText; 

  if (uc.checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
     strText = checkBox1. Text;
    }
```

how to know whether multiple check boxes are checked if the check boxes are in User Controls?

Comment: Consider to reconsider about asking questions in StackOverflow next time! Your question is not qualified by community's patterns.

Comment: @MahanGM What improvements would you suggest?  Blanketly telling new posters that their questions aren't up to "standards" is not helpful and discourages new participants.

Comment: Well this is how I've been told by others when I first came to the SO, but since you're making sense I'd do it next time.

Answer (score 1):

To find out how many checkboxes are checked you can use

```
 uc.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked).Count();
```

if count is greater than 1 then multiple are checked..

If you are only checking a couple of checkboxes then it *is* better to just check them

```
if(firstCheckbox.Checked && secondCheckbox.Checked)
```

Comment: I used this code but it is not working ,Even though the Check Boxes are checked .it is showing checked is false.So If condition is getting false and cursor is going to else condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (`&&`) logical operator. It performs both logical statements (However, if the first is false it will not check the next one)

```
if (uc.checkBox1.Checked && uc.checkBox2.Checked)
    MessageBox.Show("clicked");
```

You can also loop through each `CheckBox` control in the [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) with [LINQ](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq) and test if they are all checked. If the amount of checked boxes

```
//If the amount of checkboxes is == to the amount of checked checkboxes
if (uc.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(x => x.Checked))
MessageBox.Show("clicked");
```

You can get the number of checked checkboxes also with

```
uc.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked).Count()
```

Comment: I used this code but it is  not working ,Even though the Check Boxes are checked .it is showing checked is false.So If condition is getting false and  cursor is going to  else condition

Answer (score 0):

I would not peek into the controls of the user control- that makes it difficult to change the
user control at a later time.

I would add a property to `UCMultiple` to indicate how many (or which ones) are checked.  If you just care about is if ALL are checked and/or how many are checked it would look something like this:

```
public bool AllAreChecked
{
    return uc.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(x => x.Checked);
}
public int NumberChecked
{
    return uc.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(x => x.Checked);
}
```

If you want to know about *specific* checkboxes then there's not a generic solution - we'd need to know more about the control - how are the checkboxes generated?  Is there some external meaning to each checkbox?